# Nesting try-except blocks leads to overly indented code

Tags: python, exception, coding-style, indentation

I have a rather philosophical problem writing Python code. Normally it is considered good style to use as many `try-except-else` blocks as necessary to handle all expectable cases. But I find that this is approach sometimes leads to unnecessarily many levels of indentation that makes it difficult to keep the line count below 80 and suggest nonexistent hierarchical structure in the code. I feel I'm missing some sort of  *"GOTO"* statement or similar *jump* to cope with this. Therefore I'm wondering if I'm missing some coding style, or Python statement, or pattern, to improve my Python code.

I'll put a more concrete example. Let's think I'm defining a function, and I'm within a loop, where various things could go wrong. Each thing is sufficient to make the rest of the code within the loop skippable, which I normally skip with `continue` in a way similar to:

```py
def mu_func()
    failed = False
    for i in range(100):
        try:
            pass
            # we try something that might raise an exception
        except:
            print("something went wrong by reason #1")
            failed = True
            continue
        try:
            pass
            # we try something that might raise an exception
        except:
            print("something went wrong by reason #2")
            failed = True
            continue
        try:
            pass
            # we try something that might raise an exception
        except:
            print("something went wrong by reason #3")
            failed = True
    # some cleanup code at the end of the function
    # that depends on the errors raised
    return failed
```

The important thing to note here is that since we are within a loop, the `continue` statement saves me from having to use an `else` statement to skip the rest of the code if any exception is raised. Therefore the indentation level does not keep growing. Also note that I cannot just exit from the exception handling, because I need to do some cleanup right before returning from the function.

Now note what happens when we are **not within a loop**:

```py
def mu_func()
    failed = False
    try:
        pass
        # we try something that might raise an exception
    except:
        print("something went wrong by reason #1")
        failed = True
    else:
        try:
            pass
            # we try something that might raise an exception
        except:
            print("something went wrong by reason #2")
            failed = True
        else:
            try:
                pass
                # we try something that might raise an exception
            except:
                print("something went wrong by reason #3")
               failed = True
    # some cleanup code at the end of the function
    # that depends on the errors raised
    return failed
```

¿See the difference? If want to skip the rest of the code after any exception has been raised, I have to put inside an `else` statement everything below, which trivially increases a level of indent from that point on. This not only leads to annoying code where it is difficult to to keep the line count below 80 characters. The worst aspect is that these nested `try-except-else` blocks suggest some sort of hierarchy in the code, which is artificial. All exceptions are equally important. This can be easily appreciated in the first example where the order of the `try-except` blocks could be nicely exchanged without touching the indent and without affecting the functionality.

Is there a Python statement, or pattern, that allows me to skip the rest of the code once an exception is handled, that precludes me from having to add more and more indent levels? **Am I misusing the `else` statement?** I'm tempted to put everything within a trivial 1-iteration loop so I have access to the `continue` statement to perform the *jump to the end of block* statement that I'm missing.

Comment: I think there are several things you could do, depending on the semantics you are trying to implement with `mu_func`. Can you simply return early from an `except` block instead of using an `else` block?

Comment: No, simply using `return` in the exception handling does not fix the problem because I need to carry some *cleanup* tasks to return a meaningful value at the end of the function. I don't want to replicate this cleanup inside every exception block.

Comment: You should include that in the question, then.

Comment: Fair point. Added this remark to the question.

Answer (score 2):

What about using:

```
def mu_func()
    failed = False
    try:
        pass
        # we try something that might raise an exception
    except ExceptionClass1():
        print("something went wrong by reason #1")
        failed = True
    except ExceptionClass2():
        print("something went wrong by reason #2")
        failed = True
    except ExceptionClass3():
        print("something went wrong by reason #3")
        failed = True
    except ExceptionClass4():
        print("something went wrong by reason #4")
        failed = True
    return failed
```

Comment: The problem is that I do not want to put a lot of code inside `try`. There are many things and very different that can go wrong there. For instance `ExceptionClass1` might be raised in different parts of the `try` block and they require different handling.

Comment: Is it possible that your mu_func is violating the principle of separation of concerns? If your function can't be returned on failure and can't handle the exceptions in a way that makes your indenting out of control, that would typically be a code smell for the function is doing to much work. For instance I recently refactored some code that called an API and then did some logic with the results of the api call into two separate functions, while the only function that called the api function was the function that called the api and ran the logic, it allowed me to simplify testing.

Comment: I do not think this is the case. My function does one thing: get a bunch of URLs from a given webpage. But to do so it has to do a number of actions using `selenium`, each of which can fail independently. At the end of the function it returns a summary that summarises the work. Nearly each action in the function, albeit closely related to the rest, can fail is slightly different ways, and requires slightly different actions. Each fail is critical and makes the rest of the function skippable. And each execution has to end providing feedback of what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I have found 2 *solutions* to the problem. I'll post them here to either stimulate further discussion or help others in my situation. Still, I won't mark this as *the answer* because I find them more like a workaround than a proper solution. They are to some extent based on [the answers to this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/260207/how-to-clean-up-nested-try-except-else) (whose accepted answer I do not think it solves the problem).

**Solution using a dummy loop**

Here the idea is to *fake* a loop to have access to the `continue` statement that allows you to jump to the end of function.

```
def mu_func()
    failed = False
    for _ in range(1):
        try:
            pass
            # we try something that might raise an exception
        except Exception1:
            print("something went wrong by reason #1")
            failed = True
            continue
        try:
            pass
            # we try something that might raise an exception
        except Exception2:
            print("something went wrong by reason #2")
            failed = True
            continue
        try:
            pass
            # we try something that might raise an exception
        except Exception3:
            print("something went wrong by reason #3")
            failed = True
    # some cleanup code at the end of the function
    # that must be executed before leaving
    return failed
```

This solution works, but it is very ugly because uses a for loop in a *creative* way that is clearly not what it was designed for.

**Solution using 2-level exception handling**

Here the idea is to define and use a general exception, and use it to translate the exception type to signal that something went wrong (but it was already handled) and then basically send the execution flow to the end.

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def mu_func()
    failed = False
    try:
        try:
            pass
            # we try something that might raise an exception
        except Exception1:
            print("something went wrong by reason #1")
            raise MyException
        try:
            pass
            # we try something that might raise an exception
        except Exception2:
            print("something went wrong by reason #2")
            raise MyException
        try:
            pass
            # we try something that might raise an exception
        except Exception3:
            print("something went wrong by reason #3")
            raise MyException
    except MyException:
        failed = True
    # some cleanup code at the end of the function
    # that depends on the errors raised
    return failed
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to wrap the for loop with a `try-except` block:

```py
def mu_func():
    try:
        for i in range(100):
            # we try something that might raise an exception
            action_1()
            print("action #1 succeeds")

            action_2()
            print("action #2 succeeds")

            action_3()
            print("action #3 succeeds")

    except:
        print("something went wrong!")
        failed = True

    else:
        failed = False

    return failed
```

If you have other logic in your for loop, I'd suggest wrapping only the logic that might raise an exception:

```py
def mu_func():
    for i in range(100):
        try:
            # we try something that might raise an exception
            action_1()
            print("action #1 succeeds")

            action_2()
            print("action #2 succeeds")

            action_3()
            print("action #3 succeeds")

        except:
            print("something went wrong!")
            failed = True
            break

        # here we might do other stuff in the loop
        ...
    
    else:
        failed = False

    return failed
```

Comment: As I commented to Michael's answer, I'd like to be very specific with the error handling, so I do not want to put a lot of stuff within the same `try` block.